# How to append a string value during assignment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Hey i dont know if that is possible but i want to set a given variable in js by **reference**.

What i want to do is, that each time i pass a string to the function `addstring` that the value of the textfield is added like **+=**

```
function addstring(string)
{
    document.getElementById("string").value = string; // its a textfield

}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Do you mean assigning a string reference to the element value so that the value changes when the string changes?

Comment: It's not clear to me what about your actual question involves passing by reference.

Comment: This is what happens when a question is unclear, you get a lot of mixed answers that are just guessing at the true meaning of what's being asked.

Comment: Hmmm.. the question is more about string concatenation, yea? I was puzzled by the "variable by reference". :P

Comment: "passing variable by reference" has nothing to do with provided example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` works fine.

```
var str = "stack";
str += "overflow";

console.log(str); //alert(str); Use firebug!!
```

> > stackoverflow

Comment: @streetparade: show the code where you are adding and the error you are getting. (use firebug(add-on) on firefox or Developer Tools (ctrl+shift+j) if on Chrome)

Comment: hmm.. this worked for me 
document.getElementById("string").value +=string;

But this didnt work

 var sending = document.getElementById("string").value;
 sending+ = string;

Comment: @streetparade: Right, because what you've done there is retrieve the value of the text box's content into `sending`, and then adding your string to that value -- which at that point has nothing to do with the text box.

Comment: Remember that a += b is shorthand for a = a + b, it isn't a string version of array.push(foo) which does change array itself.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript does not support passing parameters by reference.

This link offers a good breakdown and some workarounds- [Passing by Value or reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

Answer (score 2):

If its a reference to an input text filed then you can use the value property

```
function addstring(string)
{
    document.getElementById("string").value += string.value;

}
```

See **[value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/textbox.value)**

Answer (score 1):

Your code example will work just fine with `+=`; complete example below. This suggests the problem you're having lies elsewhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addstring(string)
{
    document.getElementById('string').value += string;
}
</script>
</head>
<body><div>
<input type='text' id='string' value=''>
<br><input type='button' value='One' onClick="addstring('one');">
<input type='button' value='Two'     onClick="addstring('two');">
<input type='button' value='Three'   onClick="addstring('three');">
</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("string").value = document.getElementById("string").value + string;`

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `+=`? Why look up the element multiple times?

Comment: Hy thanks for the fast answer, unfortunatly the += doesnt work, i dont know why

Comment: @streetparade: Yes it does (http://pastie.org/864704). This suggests the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the object by first converting it to JSON (watch out for circular references) and then parse it back again.  Like so:

```
function clone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

This uses the internal browser's JSON routines (safer & faster than using an external resource).  If you simply must have backwards compatibility you can download the core JSON routines from JSON.org.

Answer (score -1):

*Javascript does not support passing parameters by reference - Not true*

Actually it does. Prototyping makes it possible to create true references to all kinds of javascript objects, including strings.

By true reference I mean when:

- Changes made to a variable or object
  passed by reference is
  reflected on the actual variable
  beeing passed
- The change is seen by all
  references to the same variable
- Everyone knowing the reference may
  change the referenced variable

To create a true reference to a variable:

- Create a constructor function
- Prototype your reference variables on
  the constructor
- DO NOT declare variables with the
  same name inside the constructor
  function!
- Create a change() function which
  **changes the prototyped variable** or do
  so directly
- Optional: Create a change() function-reference
  inside your constructor which is set
  to the ChangeRef() function uppon
  creation

Changes made this way will be seen and may be changed by all other TestRef() objects

```
function TestRef(s) {
    this.string = 'Own test-string: ' + s;
    this.change = ChangeRef;
}
function ChangeRef(s) {
    TestRef.prototype.refStr = s;
    return TestRef.prototype.refStr;
}
r = 'RefStr';
TestRef.prototype.refStr = r; // PROTOTYPE => 'RefStr', copy of r

s = new TestRef('s'); // Obj.string = Own test-string: s, Obj.refStr = RefStr
o = new TestRef('o'); // Obj.string = Own test-string: o, Obj.refStr = RefStr
ChangeRef('ChangedStr');  // Change referenced string!
TestRef.prototype.refStr; // => ChangedStr, referenced string changed
r; // => RefStr, original string intact
x = new TestRef('x'); // Obj.string = Own test-string: x, Obj.refStr = ChangedStr. New sees changed string
s; // => Obj.string = Own test-string: s, Obj.refStr = ChangedStr. Old sees changed string
o; // => Obj.string = Own test-string: o, Obj.refStr = ChangedStr. Old sees changed string
s.change('Changed by local function');
x; // => Obj.string = Own test-string: o, Obj.refStr = Changed by local function
```

Comment: Using a reference != pass by reference. What we mean by true pass by reference, e.g. in C++, is you can pass a variable into a function (not create some "reference" object; but pass the variable directly), and the function can assign to that variable (not call some method on it; assign) as if the variable was assigned to in the original scope. This is not possible in JavaScript.