# How to return from a $.each operation? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
var t = $.each(templos_cache, function(f,g){
 $.each(g.requer, function(h,j){
  if (parseFloat(g.id) == id){
   alert(j.nome); // OK, return 'afrodite'.
   return j.nome; // wrong, return [Object object].
  }
  });
  return '';
 });
```

Looking at the code we can see the problem... i can do a set in a variable out of scope but i think that can exist some more elegant way to do this.

Comment: return or break out of ?

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible to do this, you'll need to set `t` out of scope.

Answer (score 12):

To break out of `$.each()`, simply `return false;` from the callback function. As quoted from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a
>   particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false.
>   Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it
>   will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

**Edit:**

Upon realising you may want to return a value, you could simply pass an object to the callback function as this is passed by reference. See [How to append a string value during assignment in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423868/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript) - this isn't at all any more elegant though, so I'd stick with just setting a variable outside of `$.each` as colinmarc said.

Comment: that's not what the asker is asking!

Comment: @colinmarc I just realised this - I've amended the answer

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, setting a variable seems like the most elegant way to do it, like you mentioned:

```
var foo = '';
$.each(some_list, function(i, e){
   ...
   if(something) foo = 'stuff';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in THEORY something like this should do what you want.  it should loop through templos_cache, and inside loop through g.requer until id matches g.id.  in that case it will set returnValue, and break out of the inside $.each loop.  and in the outside loop it checks if returnValue has been set, if so, breaks out of the loop.

I haven't actually tested this. but it seems solid

```
var returnValue = ''; 

$.each(templos_cache, function(f,g){
    $.each(g.requer, function(h,j){
        if (parseFloat(g.id) == id){
             returnValue = j.nome;
             return false;
        }
     });
     if(returnValue != ''){
         return false;
     }

});

var t = returnValue;
```

Comment: Admittedly, I love jquery, but this is a good highlight of how there are times when being able to define a new control structure (that doesn't really execute in it's own callstack level) is a useful feature for a language. It would allow you to actually return the value you're interested in and cleanly shortcircuit the rest of the logic.

Comment: @RHSeeger: yea, it's true, it's certainly not perfect.  sometimes a plain old for loop is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `$.map` instead:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var y = $(x).map(function(i, n){
    return n < 4 ? n+1 : undefined;
});
// y == [2, 3, 4]
```

If you only return one value, `y` will be `[val]` and you can always access it with `y[0]`