# Automatically updating the actual parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to pass a primitive variable (like a string) by reference when calling a java script method?
Which is equivalent of out or ref keyword in C#.

I have a variable like `var str = "this is a string";` and passing the str into my function and automatically have to reflect the change in str when i change the argument value

```
function myFunction(arg){
    // automatically have to reflect the change in str when i change the arg value
    arg = "This is new string";
    // Expected value of str is "This is new string"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373157/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-function-with-parameters

Comment: check this out: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a string by reference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308624/pass-a-string-by-reference-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423868/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript alemjerus's answer to that is probably what you want. Convert it to an object.

Comment: @Dan, this doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that function. Here, the OP simply wants to know the best way to pass a function argument by reference in JS; the referenced question deals with references *to* a function object itself.

Comment: I have referred all of the above links before posting it. It seems the answers are satisfied the persons who asked. But, not it was a better answer right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitive types, that is strings/numbers/booleans are passed by value.
Objects such as functions, objects, arrays are "passed" by reference.

So, what you want won't be possible, but the following will work:

```
        var myObj = {};
        myObj.str = "this is a string";
        function myFunction(obj){
            // automatically have to reflect the change in str when i change the arg value
            obj.str = "This is new string";
            // Expected value of str is "This is new string"
        }
        myFunction(myObj);
        console.log(myObj.str);
```

Comment: This is mostly true, but [pedants will tell you that JavaScript is pure pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9070366/201952), and the *value* passed for objects is itself a reference.  However, this is confusing, and from a practical standpoint, it basically looks like objects are passed by reference.

Comment: Well, yes, that is what I actually wanted to say.